# Proof or counterexample about sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a(n) is a bounded sequence of positive real numbers such that a(n+1)/a(n) converges to L then L=<1.

If a(n) and b(n) are two sequences of positive real numbers such that both tend to infinity then their quotient either tends to infinity or converges to some real number L.

These are the two propositions I don't see how to manage, any help would be great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Answer on first question:

Assume that $L>1$. Then $L>K>1$ for some $K$ and for $n$ large enough - let's say $n\geq N$ - this leads to $a_{n+1}/a_n>K$, hence $a_{n+1}>Ka_n$. Then $a_{N+m}>K^{m}a_N$ contradicting that the sequence is bounded. So  $L>1$ cannot be true and we conclude that $L\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first proposition, you need to reason by the opposite. Suppose $L>1$, then after some $n_0$ you have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge \frac{L+1}{2}>1,\quad \forall n\ge n_0.$$ This implies that $$a_n\ge a_{n_0} \left(\frac{L+1}{2}\right)^{n-n_0}\to \infty\text{ as } n\to \infty,$$
which is a contradiction to boundedness of your sequence.

It's easy to build a counterexample for the second proposition. Take, for example,

$$a_n = n$$
$$b_n=\begin{cases}2n,&n \text{ is odd}\\n/2,& n\text{ is even}.\end{cases}$$
Both sequences diverge to infinity, yet their ratio is iscillating: $$2,\frac 12,2,\frac 12,2,\frac 12,\dots $$

Comment: Oh yes, right, nice!

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, use the fact that
$$ a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \dotsm \frac{a_2}{a_1} \cdot a_1 $$
If the ratios on the RHS converge to $L$ then the RHS should behave roughly like $L^n$, which if $L>1$ would mean that it's unbounded.  (I'm omitting lots of details here.)

For the second, what other case is there?  If the quotient doesn't diverge to infinity, and doesn't converge to a real number, then it has to diverge by wandering around.  The simplest example would be oscillation: maybe
$$ \frac{a_{2n}}{b_{2n}} = 1
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{a_{2n+1}}{b_{2n+1}} = 2 $$
for example.  Can you come up with such sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, both going to infinity?

Comment: No details needed ;) It all seems very clear to me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for the first, i will prove that if $L>1$ then the sequence is unbounded.

Assume $L>1$, choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $L-\epsilon>1+\epsilon$. There exists $N$, such that for all $n>N$ $|a_{n+1}/a_n -L| < \epsilon$, in particular $a_{n+1}/a_n > 1+\epsilon$. Therefore $a_{n+k} > a_n \cdot (1+\epsilon)^k$. This shows that the sequence is unbounded.